# TGW to Outbound internet VPC with NAT gateways

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat

With ref to the reference architecture on having multiple VPCs forwarding internet request to TGW which then forward to the Outbound VPC (see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/creating-a-single-internet-exit-point-from-multiple-vpcs-using-aws-transit-gateway/), there are multiple AZ in the outbound VPC and within each AZ, there are respective subnets and NAT gateways. My question is how the TGW know which AZ (Egress-privateAZ1 / Egress-private AZ2 in diagram) to forward the packet to ? Is it a round robin or? How to configure this part? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what's in the link?  This is a QA site site and we're trying to have our own content rather than a forum with shared urls for external resources.  BTW, welcome to ServerFault.  Thanks for contributing.

Comment: The url shows an AWS reference architecture which my question is based on. Tks

Answer (score 0):

AWS have told me that as a general rule, where it is practical, traffic is kept within the AZ. This isn't a hard rule, as for example some load balancers do round robin to any AZ.

The question you've asked is theoretical, and there's no problem stated. What problem are you having? Are you trying to optimise performance, cost, or something else?

Note that going over TGW to an IGW in a central account incurs traffic cost between accounts and then out to the internet, and the same for replies. Internet gateways in each account is cheaper, but if you have enterprise requirements for monitored / controlled internet ingress or egress centralisation and the associated costs can be worthwhile.

AWS doesn't have a great enterprise story for ingress / egress control yet, so you have to build it yourself. They did release a feature at re-invent for [internet ingress routing](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-ingress-routing-simplifying-integration-of-third-party-appliances/), which can be helpful, and they have some solutions for [internet egress routing](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/controlling-vpc-egress-traffic/).

A model I've used in the past is egress is shared, including responses, with appliances such as squid or more advanced firewalls like an F5 doing egress permissions. In that case we did ingress is direct into an account, as it's cheaper, faster, and can be sufficiently protected by CloudFront / WAF / Shield / ALB.

Comment: hi Tim thanks for your reply. Yes, it enterprise requirements and it's still theoretical at this stage. My question arises from my online research on centralized NAT for egress and trying to understand how it works end to end. While several AWS videos and related articles talk about the reference design, none explained how the TGW will forward the packet to the respective NATs at respective AZ at the outbound VPC via its interface.

Comment: @Will Hi, just a note, please know you can have your account Will and user555910 merged, just use the contact us form to do so. Thanks you

Comment: I don't have anything definitive for you, but I can tell you that an AWS architect has verbally told me that in general, traffic that could go to any AZ is generally preferred to stay in the AZ. I know it's not a great answer, but it's better than nothing.